# Does complement of a set include intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If i have a Venn diagram like this

[image]

Where it asks me to shade complement of (A) union with B.Do i shade the intersection part or no?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli my bad

Comment: Shade everything. Then go with an eraser over $A\cup B$. Will you have erased $A\cap B$ as well?

Comment: Hint: where are things not in A? Where are things in B?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The OP is after the untion of the complement of $A$ with $B$, not of the complement of the union of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How can you tell?

Comment: @bof Because at the bottom of the picture it's written $A'\cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

To shade the union of two sets on a Venn diagram, shade one set, then shade the other set.

When you do this for $A'$ and then for $B$ you will discover whether 
$A\cap B$ gets shaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to keep in mind the 'brackets' when going for such questions. From what is written, I assume that you're asking for the shading of $(AUB)^c$ Then, first shade all of A and B (By definition of a union). Whatever portion if leftover, is the region $(AUB)^c$ (by definition of set complement)$?

Edit:
So it says $A'UB$. Might be useful to go step by step:

1) What is $A'$?

2) What does union mean?

To answer your question, yes, the intersection part would be shaded as that part is included in B and we take the union of B with A'.